# Django custom formset validation with additional data from other forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, django-validation

To validate my formset, I need to use additional data (outside of formset). How do I pass that data to validation function when it is located in `BaseFormSet`. Along with my formset, the `request.POST` also contains the `country_id` I need for validation. Also I need the user from session during validation. Here is my validation code bellow:

```
class BaseShippingTupleFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        for form in self.forms:
            country = TranslatedCountry.objects.get(id=country_id) #  how to get country
            shippings = ShippingTuple.objects.filter(country=country, user=user) #  how to get user
            for s in shippings:
                if value_from > s.value_from and value_from < s.value_to:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(("Please enter a value that does not overlap with already existing "
                                                 "shipping tuples for the same country ("+country.translated_name+")"))
```

Inline comment indicate where the variables are missing (`country_id` and `user`). Any tip or direction is appreciated.

### Solution

After adding the custom `__init__` method like suggested in answer by @Evgeny Barbashov and fixing some other issues, here is the working solution:

```
def view_with_args(request, country_id, amount):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    country = TranslatedCountry.objects.get(id=country_id)

    CustomArgsFormSet = formset_factory(ShippingTupleForm, formset=BaseShippingTupleFormSet, extra=int(amount)-1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = CustomArgsFormSet(country, user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            # save validated forms
            return redirect('success')
        else:
            context["formset"] = formset
            return render(request, 'user/dashboard/view_template.html', context)
    else:
        context["formset"] = CustomArgsFormSet(country, user)
        return render(request, 'user/dashboard/view_template.html', context)
```

### Note

Tricky thing that needs attention are arguments to base formset class with custom init! The arguments need to be passed as non-keyword (see view above) and before the `request.POST` and alike, since they are unnamed args. Also they need to be in correct order, custom arguments first and then `request.POST` etc.

If the order is wrong the `__init__` method will map the arguments incorrectly and the error messages are confusing. Otherwise the python does not allow `non-keyword arg after keyword arg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply provide a custom **init** method for you formset:

```
class BaseShippingTupleFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(country_id, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self._country_id = country_id
        self._user = user
        super(BaseShippingTupleFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then use self._country_id and self._user in clean method

Answer (score 1):

@evgeny's code didn't work for me, but this did:

```
class BaseShippingTupleFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, country_id, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self._country_id = country_id
        self._user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```